# Как перенести кодирующую функцию из js в python 3?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, кодировка, cryptojs

Имеется функция:

```
function Signature(value) {
  var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(value);
  return (hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)); 
}
```

Нужно перенести её в python 3. Много гуглил но так ничего и не нашел. Буду сильно рад вашей помощи, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import hashlib
import base64

def signature(value):
    return base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(value.encode('utf-8')).digest())
```

```
signature('message')
# b'q1MKE+RZFJgrefm34/uplM/R8/si9xzqGvvwK0YMbR0='

signature('message').decode('utf-8')
# 'q1MKE+RZFJgrefm34/uplM/R8/si9xzqGvvwK0YMbR0='
```